# How do I set up my computer to serve website using web2py?

Tags: hosting, web2py, portforwarding

I've got web2py working so I can access my webapp from my computer locally. I also have tornado working and listening on port 8080 as I want to use websockets.

I've chosen the "Public (0.0.0.0)" option when firing up the server and listening on port 8000.

I've set up port forwarding on my [router](http://media2.comcast.net/anon.comcastonline2/support/help/faqs/wireless_gateway/HOW5220_TC_8717_User_Guide.pdf) from port 80 to port 8000 using the "other" function of the guide p.58.

When typing "what is my ip" it seems to be an IPv6 IP so no idea if that matters but I tried to check if I've done it correctly by going to this site http://www.ipv6proxy.net/index.php and trying to navigate to my IP address that google spit out when I typed "what is my ip?" but get a `couldn't connect to the host` message.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm relatively new to this.

To explain motivation I simply want to do a dry run of the website and websockets online. I think there are a tonne of security risks associated with what I'm doing and this is simply a learning exercise for me and do not intend to host the website this way. I do want to understand how I would do this though.

**EDIT**

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: This is most likely a firewall issue. What OS are you running? also (while still a firewall rule) most ISPs will block port 80 to residential accounts, so you may try a random port and access it from `http://<IPADDRESS>:<RANDOM_PORT>` if this is the problem you may also hit problems with other well-used "alias" ports like 8080, 8000 etc try something like 54267 (I just bashed my number pad to get that). The real solution would be to host this on a computer from any hosting provider. Also to check if your ISP is the cause, you could  try to connect from another host on your local network

Comment: interesting if I do it on a random port then I get a `connect() timed out` message instead of a `couldn't connect to the host`, does this help at all?

Comment: maybe, I would usually associate a timeout with a firewall, but (being more familiar with CentOS/REHL/Fedora) I had to do some research about Ubuntu, and discovered that shockingly the firewall is [disabled by default](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html#firewall-ufw). Did you happen to enable UFW? If so please follow the guide in the link I just provided to open the random port. You may also have a firewall on you router/switch/etc (whatever is sitting between your computer and the internet).